# C void pointer with ternary operator

Tags: c, ternary-operator, void-pointers

I have a problem with a void pointer in use with a ternary condition operator.

In  case of:

```
int x = 5;
void * pointer = &x;
printf("x: %d \n", 1 == 1 ? (*((int*)pointer)) : (*((char*)pointer)));
```

It writes to console the number 5, whitch is correct activity. But when I change in last line char to double:

```
printf("x: %d \n", 1 == 1 ? (*((int*)pointer)) : (*((double*)pointer)));
```

Then it writes 0 and I don't know why. I know I can use if-else instead of it but I'm just curious why it is working that way. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Try and determine the type of the whole ternary expression (it has only one type)

Comment: Your compiler could help you if you enable (or read) the warnings.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that you are using a pointer in the ternary, so your question title is completely mislead. You would see the same problem with `1 ? 5 : 5.0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of a ternary expression is the *common type* of the two branches. In the case of one branch being an `int` and the other a `double` then the result will be a `double` as well.

And you don't print a `double` value, you attempt to print an `int` value. Mismatching format specifier and value will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

For more information see e.g. [this conditional operator reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `%lf` instead of `%d`

```
int x = 5;
void * pointer = &x;
printf("x: %lf \n", 1 == 1 ? (*((int*)pointer)) : (*((char*)pointer)));
```